# Three eyed raven and Bran

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I want to know the answer to the below questions, based on your understanding of *Game of Thrones*.

If Bran is the Three-eyed-raven/Old man on the tree that was inside the cave in seasons 4 and 5.

1. How did the old man get there, was that old man like an illusion, I don't think it's an illusion because the old man got killed.
2. Why didn't Bran die, when the old man died, if they are the same? Does he have multiple lives?
3. Is this some kind of a past-present-future type scenario where one character knows what's happening in the entire plot. The whole thing seems confusing to me at least.

Are the above questions yet to be answered on the show in the following episodes in season 8?

Comment: This question is based on a flawed assumption, however it is not too broad.  The true question from my understanding is "who was the old man who was the Three Eyed Raven, and how does he relate to Bran".  @FirstSlack, does this encompass the question that you're looking to solve?

Comment: Dku, Understood my question and I got my answer.

Comment: I want the moderator to explain, what was "too broad"? If it was considered to be 'Too Broad' then there would be hundreds of comments and a fight in the comment section.

Comment: I can't speak for AJ, but I'm assuming it's the list of questions 1), 2), 3).  If you could rephrase it to remove the question list by getting at the central question you are asking (as I attempted to do in my comment), I would expect it to be re-opened.

Comment: If I rephrase my question, then the answer must be rephrased. I like it this way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Three-eyed Raven is an ancient human greenseer (someone able to use greensight, which is the prophetic ability Bran has). How he came to be under the weirwood tree remains a mystery, but he tells Bran that he has been there for 1,000 years -

> Three-eyed Raven: You think I wanted to sit here for 1,000 years watching the world from a distance as the roots grew through me?
>
> Bran: So why did you?
>
> Three-eyed Raven: I was waiting for you.

Before meeting the Three-eyed Raven, Bran experiences greensight dreams but is unable to trigger the ability at will. Touching the roots of the weirdwood allows him to use greensight, indicating that the roots running through the Three-eyed Raven have special powers. This appears to be why the Three-eyed Raven is there, drawing from the power of the weirwood to use greensight and have unnaturally long life.

Bran is not literally the same as the Three-eyed Raven, but rather his replacement. This is why the Three-Eyed Raven drew Bran to him and attempted to teach him to master greensight. Unfortunately, Bran instead misuses it and lures the Night King to the cave. After the Three-eyed Raven is killed, Benjen Stark remarks on his passing:

> Meera: Why did you help us?
>
> Benjen: The Three-Eyed Raven sent for me.
>
> Meera: The Three-Eyed Raven's dead.
>
> Benjen: Now he lives again.

This implies that Three-eyed Raven is a title and Bran is the new Three-eyed Raven. It is yet to be revealed what his exact purpose is.

Comment: Nice, Did the tv-show tell us about how the Night-King was able to touch Bran when on greensight?

Comment: No, we are left to speculate. It would appear that the Night King has mastery over greensight.

Comment: @FirstSlack: It's an often recurring feature where magic cannot be tampered with unless it's by other (sometimes specific) magic. Dragons and White Walkers are two opposing forms of magic (hence why dragonfire can kill wights). The Wall was built to repel the Walkers, but it was never built to repel dragons. Tearing it down was only possible with a dragon. SImilarly, greensight is a form of magic, and the Night King was created through magic. It's not unexpected that they can somehow interact with one another. In general, "magic can affect magic" is the default explanation.

Comment: It would be great if Bran's story ends with him getting hurled back in time to become the original though

Answer (score 0):

The three-eyed raven is any person who knows everything that happened in the past or can go to any point in the past and know what happened.

The old man possess this powers and he transferred this powers to Bran.

In the season 8, episode 2, Bran confirms that the Knight king wants to kill him because he is "Memory".

> He (the Knight King) wants to erase this world and I am its memory.